# QApplication instance/qtbot fixture causes travis-ci to abort and core dump

Tags: python-3.6, travis-ci, pytest, pyside2, pytest-qt

Working on understanding how to go about automated unit testing for PySide2-based applications. However, whenever I attempt to initialize a `QApplication` instance within the tests, be it through `PySide2` itself or through `pytest-qt`'s qtbot fixture, travis-ci aborts the test. It works locally, however.

I've attempted using the `qtbot` and `qapp` fixtures from `pytest-qt`, trying different `travis-ci` distros like `xenial` and `trusty`, as well as including the `pytest-xvfb` plugin as I've seen recommended by a similar stackoverflow question's answer, but nothing worked in any combination of the above.

```
# .travis.yml
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
cache: pip
dist: xenial
install: pip install -r requirements.txt
# running from top folder level to keep package on the path
script: python -m pytest tests/
```

```py
# tests/test_central.py
from lysiaa.central import MyWindow

def test_giveBack(qapp):
    window = MyWindow()
    assert window.giveBack(1) == 1
```

```py
# lysiaa/central.py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def giveBack(self, param):
        return param
```

When `travis-ci` tries running this, however, it aborts with a core dump. Could anyone please help me with this issue?

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.7, pytest-4.5.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.11.0
PySide2 5.12.3 -- Qt runtime 5.12.3 -- Qt compiled 5.12.3
rootdir: /home/travis/build/robert-clayton/LYSIAA
plugins: xvfb-1.2.0, qt-3.2.2
collected 1 item                                                               
tests/test_central.py /home/travis/.travis/functions: line 104:  4092 Aborted                 (core dumped) python -m pytest tests/
The command "python -m pytest tests/" exited with 134.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured this out for a similar project. I think this is related:
[Running pytest-qt on CircleCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824357/running-pytest-qt-on-circleci)

I tried to set `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` as an environment variable in Travis-CI, but did not get any information out of that. However, I succeeded by adding

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - x11-utils
    - libxkbcommon-x11-0
services: xvfb
dist: xenial
```

to `.travis.yml`. Note that for some reason you have to make sure that there is no `before-install` section in `.travis.yml`.

Here is a working travis.yml: https://github.com/AFM-analysis/PyJibe/blob/c4406fd712d778e2f644d6d03fce0db5688801bb/.travis.yml

Travis-CI before: https://travis-ci.org/AFM-analysis/PyJibe/jobs/564834411

Trivis-CI after: https://travis-ci.org/AFM-analysis/PyJibe/jobs/565690825

[EDIT: I have added `services: xvfb` and `dist: xenial` as per DrIDK's comment]

Comment: Confirmed that this worked like a charm for the error I was running into. Thanks man, I'd all but given up on it.

Comment: The service xvfb is also required and works only on xenial. I also succeed to fix the issue using the code above and by adding dist:xenial in my travis file

Comment: @DrIDK Thanks for pointing that out---I'd forgotten that I had also added `dist: xenial` to my yml file. I'll edit my original question to include that info.

Comment: Same here! clean and painless solution to a potentially nasty issue... you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul, I tried the above and had to combine resources from a few solutions to get this to work. Hopefully this can help others!

I have this working with Python 3.8 on travis ci, but needed many more xcb packages that mentioned above.

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - x11-utils
    - libxkbcommon-x11-0
    - libxcb-randr0-dev
    - libxcb-xtest0-dev
    - libxcb-xinerama0-dev
    - libxcb-shape0-dev
    - libxcb-xkb-dev
    - libxcb-render-util0
    - libxcb-icccm4
    - libxcb-keysyms1
    - libxcb-image0
services: xvfb
```

With this configuration, pytest is running fine with pytest-qt. I had to go through one by one the dependency failures with QT until it worked.